# Xaml toggleMenuFlyoutItem

Tags: c#, xaml

The `ToggleMenuFlyoutItem` performs like a `checkbox`. I want to implement it as a `radiobutton` functionality. Whats the best way to do it. Do I have to create a `customcontrol` extending 
`MenuFlyoutItem` class(if yes, then how) or is there some other way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Template with RadioButton inside for simple MenuFlyoutItem or you can use RadioButton as content of MenuFlyoutItem. And than you can style RadioButton to look like ToggleMenuFlyoutItem or whatever you want.

As for 2019 there is [RadioMenuFlyoutItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.radiomenuflyoutitem?view=winui-2.2) in WinUI Library

Comment: Hello, I am new to the Windows programming. Can you make provide a piece of code to show what the MenuFlyoutItem might look like?

Comment: @SeakyLone you can just use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.radiomenuflyoutitem?view=winui-2.2